# How to require ''pg" gem on iron.io with iron_worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ironworker, iron.io

.worker file

```
runtime "ruby"
name "UserMailer"
merge_gem "activerecord", "=3.2.8"
merge_gem 'actionmailer', '=3.2.8'
merge_gem 'devise', '=2.1.2'
merge_gem 'pg', "=0.14.0"
merge_file "../app/views/user_mailer/new_user.html.erb" , "user_mailer"
merge_file "../app/mailers/user_mailer.rb"
merge_dir "../app/models"
merge_exec "user_mailer_worker.rb"
```

.rb file

```
require 'action_mailer' 
require 'active_record' 
require 'pg'
require 'bcrypt'
require 'devise'
require 'user_mailer.rb'
require 'models/user.rb' 

def init_mailer
  #Need to convert to proper hashes
  mailer_config = params['mailer'].inject({}) { |memo, (k, v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v; memo }
  # set default views dir to current dir
  ActionMailer::Base.prepend_view_path('.')
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = mailer_config
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
end

def setup_database
  puts "Database connection details:#{params['database'].inspect}"
  return unless params['database']
  # estabilsh database connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(params['database'])
end

init_mailer
setup_database
puts "I got '#{params.inspect}' parameters"
#send email!
# you could use here any active_record queries with models
UserMailer.new_user(User.find(params[:id])).deliver!
```

I have uploaded code to iron worker but i got following output

```
Skipping ruby gem with name='pg' and version='0.14.0' as it contains native extensions, switching to full remote build should fix this
```

and after i queue task on iron.io i got error

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- pg (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /task/user_mailer_worker.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from __runner__.rb:190:in `<main>'
```

how to require 'pg' gem on iron.io ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line to .worker file:

```
full_remote_build true
```